# C++ Parser import module

Tags: c++, parsing, interpreter

I'm writing interpreter for my programming language. I saw good realisation of interpreter on Java, but each know that Java works very slow. So, I'm developing on C++, but I've got a problem. Exactly: Java has beautiful thing as Java Reflection. And, when parser sees "import" statement, it takes the name of "module" (Already exists class in interpreter program) and using Reflection takes instance of class by name. So easy, but not in C++. C++ hasn't tricks to take instance of class by name. Could we help me?)

Comment: I think you need to explain your situation a bit more. You're trying to resolve import statements directly in your parser, right (at least I don't see how any of the question makes sense, if you're only parsing it)? And in Java you would use reflection for that? How? You say you'd use it to load a class, but what class? Were you compiling your language to Java class files? If so, what are you compiling to now?

Comment: So, Modules - inside classes in interpreter which implement "Module" interface (it's interface with "init" function). When parser sees "include" word, he takes next word (=name) and gets by Reflection Utils (Class.forname(...)) class and executes init func. For example, we have the program: "include 'test'...". In this, parser will get class "test", which exists in interpreter package and executes init method of class instance. In the init method program add functions/variables to the big list of functions/variables, which will be used later.

Comment: _"each know that Java works very slow"_ This is knowledge from the 1990s (almost thirty years ago!). Update your knowledge.

Comment: anyway, C++ works faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's my understanding of your situation so far, as I understood it from question and comment:

1. You have modules, which are implemented as Java classes, not files written in your own language.
2. When you parse an import statement, you use reflection to find a class with the given name in the modules package (meaning there's a package that contains all the module classes and nothing else and that each module class has the same name as the module that it represents)
3. And then presumably you call functions from the imported module by calling methods on the instantiated objects, again using reflection.

So you're right, you can't do it like that in C++.

What you can do is to have a map from module names to module objects, and then each module should have a map of its own functions.

Comment: hm, thanks, I will think about it. I thought about it and made sure that this way the best.